# De kie venas la vorto «ĉikani»?

Tags: etymology

Ĉu iu scias la etimologion de «ĉikani», kaj el kiu lingvo ĝi venas, ktp?

Mi suspektis, ke ĝi eble venas de la japana vorto 痴漢 (chikan), kiu signifas pli-malpli "molestanto", kaj ĝia signifo do similas al "ĉikananto". Sed ŝajne "ĉikani" estas vorto el la Fundamento, kaj ne ŝajnas al mi tre probabla, ke Zamenhof elektus japanan vorton por tio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laŭ [Vilborg](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etimologia_Vortaro_de_Esperanto), ĝi venis de franca *chicaner*, germana *schikanieren*, kaj pola *szykanowac'*. Por komparo, li mencias ankaŭ la anglan *chicanery* kaj la portugalan *chicanar*. Li cetere notas:

> Origine la citita etimologio koncernis nur la formon, ĉar Zamenhof atribuis al la radiko la signifon "babili malicaĵojn"; post kiam *klaĉi* estis oficialigita (4-a Oficiala Aldono), la signifo de *ĉikan/i* konformiĝis al tiu de la nacilingva responda vorto.

Answer (score 2):

Ĝi estas franca vorto de nekonata fonto.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chicanery